# Looping a string reader in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I'm working on a project that takes patient id's, number of patient blood  pressure records, displays those, then takes an average blood pressure reading based on 1 or more blood pressure records for that patient. All the data is read from a file. This is the code I got so far,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Initialize Required Variables For Program
    int patientCount = 0;
    string id;
    string rHowMany; //String To Read From File
    int howMany = 0;
    int howManyCount = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int avg2;
    string line;
    int numbre_lines = 0;
    ifstream reader ("data.txt"); //Open The Data File To Be Read From

    do
    {
        reader >> id;
        reader >> howMany;
        cout << "The Patient ID Is: " << id << endl;
        cout << "The Number Of Blood Pressure Record This Patient Has Is: " <<
                     howMany << endl;
        do
        {
            reader >> avg;
            avg = avg + avg;
        }
        while (reader != "\n");
        cin.clear();
        avg = avg / howMany;
        cout << "The Patient Average BP Reading Is: " << avg;
    }
    while (!EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

I attempted using for loops and while loops together, but was getting some really strange errors that I couldn't resolve. So I decided to do it with a nested while loop. Unfortunately, the code just freezes on execution. The data file is there, with the correct data in it, but for some reason I just can't get the program to work. If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

--Edit
Here is what one of the files looks like

```
4567 4 180 140 170 150
5643 2 125 150
```

Comment: what if `reader` is never equal to `"\n"`?

Comment: How is the `while (!EOF);` condition ever satisfied?

Comment: It would become false at the end of the file i think

Comment: Sam, I'm not sure what you mean, isn't "\n" equivalent to the end of a line?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that all of the blood pressure values are on one line. Don't you trust 'howMany'?

Comment: I'll post a sample file of what one of these records look like real quick

Comment: You are looking for `reader.eof()` but I doubt that's the only thing hanging you up.  If the file is telling you how many pressures there are then use it for your loop.

Comment: I attempted using a while loop to find how many records there were in one line, then using a for loop to read that many blood pressure records, however, that was causing some strange errors so I had to try the nested while loop. The original idea was to make it so that the program was dynamic, and you could enter 2 blood pressure records, or 200 for one patient, and you could have an infinite amount of patients.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader != "\n"
```

is always true, because `reader` is an `ifstream` and "\n" is a string literal.
Even if both are converted to `void*` (which I suspect since it apparently compiles), the result of converting `reader` to `void*` will never be the adress of the literal.

Your logic is a tad flawed, too - `avg` would be twice the value of the last value read if the loop worked.

Fixing it is left as an exercise.